# Pointing Julia Studio at a different binary

Tags: julia, julia-studio

I'm on mac.

As far as I know, even though Julia 0.3 is now officially released, Julia Studio still comes prepackaged with Julia 0.2.  So I went to the package contents of Julia 0.3 and pointed the path in Julia Studio at the julia folder for Julia 0.3, however I received the error message:

```
Error: Failed to start Julia.
Expected location: /opt/Julia_Studio/bin/julia-basic/bin/julia-basic
```

So I changed the julia executable in the bin folder from 'julia' to 'julia-basic', to see if that would fix things.  What happened instead was I got a bunch of deprecation warnings and while the julia interactive prompt loaded, when I tried to execute a command and hit return it just sits there stupidly not giving me anything back.  What do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It's possible, but only for point releases.

Julia as a language is evolving rapidly.  Each release of Julia Studio works only for a specific version.  Forio will be release new versions of Julia Studio with support for the official Julia 0.3 release soon.  The current master branch at https://github.com/forio/julia-studio supports Julia 0.3 but building on OSX is somewhat involved.

*Disclaimer: I work for Forio*

Answer (score 2):

Last time I checked Julia Studio, it was not possible to point it at an external Julia release. This was a limitation I have heard others complain about as well.

I cannot tell if and when this limitation is overcome.

When it is capable of pointing at an external release, I will take another look at Julia Studio.

Comment: Why would they have that option in the preferences then? if you can't actually do it?

Comment: @user1378571 I don't know.  Perhaps they are working on implementing this feature but it is not working quite well?  Someone from Forio or who knows for sure should answer.  Just trying to inform you that not long ago it was not possible so you should not take it from granted.  I would ensure that this feature is actually in place and working before spending much time on it and perhaps banging your head against a wall the way I did for a while.

Comment: @user1378571 Apparently Julia Studio dev is not progressing, see [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/julia-users/N-__nw3Wd04/eHshKzndRqgJ) on julia-users mailing list.